# Bootstrap make colums same height - align on text row

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

Is there a way to equalise the heights of a text and an image column? I want to align the height of the text block to the image block.

So that the picture is shown shortened/cropped.

```css
.row-eq-height{
  display: flex;
  }

.row-eq-height [class*="col-"]{
  border: 1px solid #000;
  
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
<div class="row row-eq-height">  
  <div class="col-md-7">
    <div class="text-container">
      <h2>Headline</h2>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et</p>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="col-md-5">
    <div class="img-container">
     <img src="https://www.placecage.com/400/400" />
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself** preferably in a [**Stack Snippet**](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do).  See [**How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/reprex)

Comment: Note: the `<img>` tag does not use and does not need a closing slash and never has in HTML.

Answer (score 1):

Found it! I doesn't work with the `<img>`, you have to insert it as a background-image.

```css
.row {
  background: #f8f9fa;
  margin-top: 20px;
}

.col {
  border: solid 1px #6c757d;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">


<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col">
      <h2>
Bit fat heading!
      </h2>

      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam</p>

    </div>
    <div class="col" style="background-image: url('https://www.placecage.com/400/400');">
    </div>
  </div>
 
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can just set the content containers to height:100%. This should be enough to achieve your desired result.

```css
p {
  height: 100%;
  background-color: grey;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-4"><p>Text</p></div>
  <div class="col-4"><p>Text<br>2</p></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you, but this is the opposite what i want to do. I want to crop the image to the length of the text collum.

Comment: ok i see. you can also get it for <img> Elements with positioning. see updated pen https://codepen.io/manoi/pen/zYxQdqP

Answer (score 0):

A workaround for this would be to give the `img` element an `absolute` position within it's container `.img-container`

This allows it to be separated from the standard document flow and therefor not affect the height of the flexbox

This gives you options to also adjust the image offset either via css or via the `style` property if you wish to view a specific part of the image

```css
.row-eq-height{
  display: flex;
}

.row-eq-height [class*="col-"]{
  border: 1px solid #000;
  
}

.img-container {
  position:relative;
  overflow:hidden;
  height:100%;
}

.img-container img {
  position:absolute;
  top: 0;
  left:0;
}

/* adding in base classes that are inherited from Bootstrap - you can exclude the below code */
.container {
  width: 80%;
}

.row {
  display:flex;
}

.col-md-7 {
  width : 58.333333%;
}

.col-md-5 {
  width : 41.666666%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
<div class="row row-eq-height">  
  <div class="col-md-7">
    <div class="text-container">
      <h2>Headline</h2>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et</p>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="col-md-5">
    <div class="img-container">
     <img src="https://www.placecage.com/400/400" />
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
```